# Move website from root to sub

Tags: options, migration

#### What am I trying to do exactly ?

Move my WP website available at example.com to example.com/subdir but I **don't** want to make it available on example.com

#### Why would I want to do such a thing ?

I want an "under construction" webpage on "example.com", but people (that I've chosen before) with the link of /subdir could access to it. In that way, visitors can still see a website and my client could as well see where am I in the process of website making.

#### What have I been trying ?

I've read all stackoverflow's post talking about something like that but nothing helped me so far.
I've done everything following tutorials available online ;

- Found & replaced example.com to example.com/subdir using WP Migrate DB plugin
- Using FTP, made a "subdir" folder & moved everything in it
- Added two lines containing siteurl & wpurl into `wp-config.php`
- Checked the "permalink" setting

  Even without trying to make a maintenance webpage, like the tutorials do, by copying/pasting `.htaccess` & `index.php` into `/subdir/../`, the trick won't work as well

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling to do such a thing, here's a simple way ;

Using the WP Dashboard, make a new page "subdir" and set is as whatever you want (for me it was a blank-page for my "under construction" page".

Then go to your theme settings and set this freshly made webpage as the main webpage & you'll be done.

At first I thought I had to do migrating work but I didn't have to do such a thing, it was a bit too much overthinking :)